# Azure Maps Route Directions Error Returns Bad Request

Tags: azure, azure-maps

Can anyone possible tell me what is wrong with this lat,lng: `54.575972,-1.235028` google maps says it's ok! ref:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/54%C2%B034'33.5%22N+1%C2%B014'06.1%22W/@54.5759722,-1.2372165,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d54.575972!4d-1.235028

Azure API Returns Bad Request!

https://atlas.microsoft.com/route/directions/json?subscription-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&api-version=1.0&query=52.042250,-0.780480:54.575972,-1.235028

Message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "400 BadRequest",
    "message": "Bad request: one or more parameters were incorrectly specified or are mutually exclusive."
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll pass this on to the dev team to investigate.

Comment: Definitely a data issue that needs to investigated further, but just to unblock you - try adding the travelMode param to the query "&travelMode=bicycle" - seems to return the right result (again ideally it should work without it)

Comment: @MichaelWesten bicycle mode works I've tried bus, truck, but really what I need is `&travelMode=car` and it doesn't work thanks for your input.

Comment: @rbrundritt it may able to debug what I found is that there is one number playing up. number 2 in lng -1.**2**35028  if you change fro any other number it works like: `-1.135028`

Comment: Changing that number though moves your coordinate about 11KM. I think the issue might be that the coordinate is evenly spaced from multiple roads and the routing service isn't sure which one to snap to. I have the team looking into this to figure out the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team found the issue. The road segment that the coordinate was snapping to was classified as a walking road, and thus the routing service wasn't able to calculate the route. The road has been reclassified and should be updated in the platform within the next couple of weeks. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Is there a platform that we can submit issues like this, because I have almost the same issue for another route and there is no way that I can trace the reason?

Comment: Production related issues can be reported to the Azure support team: https://azure.com/support For feature requests, they can be requested here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909172-azure-maps Other queries can be asked in the Azure Maps forums: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-maps.html

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Brundritt for your help